# python lxml how to find multiple markup?

Tags: lxml

I know if I want to find all `a` nodes I can use `root.xpath('.//a')`. But how should I do if I want to iterate over all `a` or `b` nodes (depth first search)?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <x><a>one</a></x>
    <x><x><b>three</b></x></x>
    <b>three</b>
</root>
```

Comment: `root.xpath('.//*[self::a or self::b]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possible ways, here are some of them.

using union operator (`|`) :

```
.//a | .//b
```

using `or` operator to allow multiple possible `self::element`, as mentioned in the comment :

```
.//*[self::a or self::b]
```

or mix of the two :

```
.//*[self::a | self::b]
```